# How much data can hold MQTT in single message?

Tags: mqtt

Is there any limit in sending(publishing) data to the topic (broker or receiver)  in mqtt for single message?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IBM wrote an [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5things/entry/5_things_to_know_about_mqtt_the_protocol_for_internet_of_things?lang=en) about MQTT.

> A payload up to 256 MB could be attached in the packets. Having a small header overhead makes this protocol appropriate for IoT by lowering the amount of data transmitted over constrained networks.

There is a limit which is 256MB.

Comment: See also the MQTT 3.1.1 specification: http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html

"This allows applications to send Control Packets of size up to 268,435,455 (256 MB)"

Comment: It should be worth noting that it's not a splendid idea to send 256MB over MQTT, since there is no resume functionality built-in. From my experience, using messages < 1 MB is a good idea.

Comment: @DominikObermaier What do you mean by "resume functionality "? What are they?